# Android CameraX Analyzer Image with format YUV_420_888 to OpenCV Mat

Tags: android, opencv, kotlin, android-camerax

With **Android CameraX Analyzer** `ImageProxy` uses `ImageReader` under the hood with a default `YUV_420_888` image format.

I'd like to convert it in OpenCV `Mat` in order to use OpenCV inside my analyzer:

```
override fun analyze(imageProxy: ImageProxy, rotationDegrees: Int) {
    try {
      imageProxy.image?.let {
        // ImageProxy uses an ImageReader under the hood:
        // https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageProxy.html
        // That has a default format of YUV_420_888 if not changed that's the default
        // Android camera format.
        // https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat.html#YUV_420_888
        // https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ImageReader.html

        // Sanity check
        if (it.format == ImageFormat.YUV_420_888
            && it.planes.size == 3
        ) {
           // TODO - convert ImageProxy.image to Mat
        } else {
          // Manage other image formats
          // TODO - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/Image.html
        }
      }
    } catch (ise: IllegalStateException) {
      ise.printStackTrace()
    }
  }
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looking at OpenCV [JavaCamera2Frame](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/java/generator/android-21/java/org/opencv/android/JavaCamera2View.java) class in its GitHub repo you can write an `Image` extension function like that:

(ported to Kotlin)

```
// Ported from opencv private class JavaCamera2Frame
fun Image.yuvToRgba(): Mat {
  val rgbaMat = Mat()

  if (format == ImageFormat.YUV_420_888
      && planes.size == 3) {

    val chromaPixelStride = planes[1].pixelStride

    if (chromaPixelStride == 2) { // Chroma channels are interleaved
      assert(planes[0].pixelStride == 1)
      assert(planes[2].pixelStride == 2)
      val yPlane = planes[0].buffer
      val uvPlane1 = planes[1].buffer
      val uvPlane2 = planes[2].buffer
      val yMat = Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC1, yPlane)
      val uvMat1 = Mat(height / 2, width / 2, CvType.CV_8UC2, uvPlane1)
      val uvMat2 = Mat(height / 2, width / 2, CvType.CV_8UC2, uvPlane2)
      val addrDiff = uvMat2.dataAddr() - uvMat1.dataAddr()
      if (addrDiff > 0) {
        assert(addrDiff == 1L)
        Imgproc.cvtColorTwoPlane(yMat, uvMat1, rgbaMat, Imgproc.COLOR_YUV2RGBA_NV12)
      } else {
        assert(addrDiff == -1L)
        Imgproc.cvtColorTwoPlane(yMat, uvMat2, rgbaMat, Imgproc.COLOR_YUV2RGBA_NV21)
      }
    } else { // Chroma channels are not interleaved
      val yuvBytes = ByteArray(width * (height + height / 2))
      val yPlane = planes[0].buffer
      val uPlane = planes[1].buffer
      val vPlane = planes[2].buffer

      yPlane.get(yuvBytes, 0, width * height)

      val chromaRowStride = planes[1].rowStride
      val chromaRowPadding = chromaRowStride - width / 2

      var offset = width * height
      if (chromaRowPadding == 0) {
        // When the row stride of the chroma channels equals their width, we can copy
        // the entire channels in one go
        uPlane.get(yuvBytes, offset, width * height / 4)
        offset += width * height / 4
        vPlane.get(yuvBytes, offset, width * height / 4)
      } else {
        // When not equal, we need to copy the channels row by row
        for (i in 0 until height / 2) {
          uPlane.get(yuvBytes, offset, width / 2)
          offset += width / 2
          if (i < height / 2 - 1) {
            uPlane.position(uPlane.position() + chromaRowPadding)
          }
        }
        for (i in 0 until height / 2) {
          vPlane.get(yuvBytes, offset, width / 2)
          offset += width / 2
          if (i < height / 2 - 1) {
            vPlane.position(vPlane.position() + chromaRowPadding)
          }
        }
      }

      val yuvMat = Mat(height + height / 2, width, CvType.CV_8UC1)
      yuvMat.put(0, 0, yuvBytes)
      Imgproc.cvtColor(yuvMat, rgbaMat, Imgproc.COLOR_YUV2RGBA_I420, 4)
    }
  }

  return rgbaMat
}
```

And so you can write:

```
override fun analyze(imageProxy: ImageProxy, rotationDegrees: Int) {
    try {
      imageProxy.image?.let {
        // ImageProxy uses an ImageReader under the hood:
        // https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageProxy.html
        // That has a default format of YUV_420_888 if not changed that's the default
        // Android camera format.
        // https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat.html#YUV_420_888
        // https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ImageReader.html

        // Sanity check
        if (it.format == ImageFormat.YUV_420_888
            && it.planes.size == 3
        ) {        
          val rgbaMat = it.yuvToRgba()
        } else {
          // Manage other image formats
          // TODO - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/Image.html
        }
      }
    } catch (ise: IllegalStateException) {
      ise.printStackTrace()
    }
  }
```

Comment: Getting java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for long org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat() (tried Java_org_opencv_core_Mat_n_1Mat and Java_org_opencv_core_Mat_n_1Mat__)

Answer (score 5):

```
 private Mat convertYUVtoMat(@NonNull Image img) {
    byte[] nv21;

    ByteBuffer yBuffer = img.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
    ByteBuffer uBuffer = img.getPlanes()[1].getBuffer();
    ByteBuffer vBuffer = img.getPlanes()[2].getBuffer();

    int ySize = yBuffer.remaining();
    int uSize = uBuffer.remaining();
    int vSize = vBuffer.remaining();

    nv21 = new byte[ySize + uSize + vSize];

    yBuffer.get(nv21, 0, ySize);
    vBuffer.get(nv21, ySize, vSize);
    uBuffer.get(nv21, ySize + vSize, uSize);

    Mat yuv = new Mat(img.getHeight() + img.getHeight()/2, img.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
    yuv.put(0, 0, nv21);
    Mat rgb = new Mat();
    Imgproc.cvtColor(yuv, rgb, Imgproc.COLOR_YUV2RGB_NV21, 3);
    Core.rotate(rgb, rgb, Core.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE);
    return  rgb;
}
```

This method converts the Camerax API YUV_420_888 image to OpenCV's Mat (RGB) object.
(Working 2021)

Answer (score 1):

@shadowsheep solution is just fine if you need to get OpenCV Mat.

but if you want to get Bitmap and don't want to add opencv library into you project you can take a look at RenderScript solution in [android/camera-samples repo](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/blob/3730442b49189f76a1083a98f3acf3f5f09222a3/CameraUtils/lib/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera/utils/YuvToRgbConverter.kt)

Also I made single Java file library at [github](https://github.com/gordinmitya/yuv2buf). It will be useful if you want to get correct ByteBuffer without any row or pixel strides for futher processing (for instance with neural network engine).

I also [compared](https://github.com/gordinmitya/yuv2buf/blob/master/README.md) all these approaches. OpenCV is the fastest.

Comment: I do need to get the Mat. [-;

Comment: This solution worked for me perfectly fine and is real fast. I was using another method but then I realized it was slowing down my real-time processing. Thumbs Up !!!